# Répétition du pronom relatif « qui » dans plusieurs relatives coordonnées par une conj. (et, ou,…)

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, syntaxe, coordination

La phrase suivante est correcte.

- Il y a des personnes *qui* n'ont pas ce droit et *qui* ne le veulent pas.

La question est de savoir si dans les phrases sur ce modèle, l'omission de la seconde occurrence du pronom résulterait en une phrase correcte dont le sens soit le même.

Comment: Le mot élision est mal utilisé dans ce contexte, "l'omission" serait plus approprié. L'élision concerne spécifiquement l'effacement de voyelle en fin de mot alors que le terme omission peut être utilisé de façon plus générale, pour parler du fait d'omettre quelque chose (ne pas l'ajouter / l'utiliser)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Quand deux propositions relatives sont coordonnées, le pronom relatif sujet qui peut être répété ou non." Source: http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4079

Pour les phrases construites de la même manière que dans la question, le sens de la phrase ne change pas en fonction de la répétition du pronom, cela est simplement une question de préférence de l'auteur.

Answer (score 1):

> Il y a des personnes qui n'ont pas ce droit et ne le veulent pas.

En effet, cette tournure est parfaitement correcte et a le même sens que la première phrase. Il est d'ailleurs très courant de ne pas répéter "qui" dans ce type de phrases.

Comment: Un bémol sur le très courant: c'est fréquent dans les écrits formels et relève d'un bon style. À l'oral, le *qui* relatif se comporte comme un pronom clitique sujet et les études de corpus ont démontré qu'il est presque systématiquement répété sur chacun des verbes coordonnés.